# Why does the Regex compiler compile in this way?

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
groupRegex = re.compile(r'(\d\d\d).(\d\d\d)-(\d\d\d\d)')                            
print(groupRegex.findall('Cell: 514.552-2345 Work: 512-323-5543'))

[('514', '552', '2345'), ('512', '323', '5543')]
```

Why doesn't it return [('514', '552', '2345')] and not the "Work" phone number? The period in this instance is acting like a hyphen. Please explain in the most basic way, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The regex compiler will compile the `.` as a regex operator and not the "dot" as a character. You must escape it to get the correct output.

```
import re
groupRegex = re.compile(r'(\d\d\d)\.(\d\d\d)-(\d\d\d\d)')                            
print(groupRegex.findall('Cell: 514.552-2345 Work: 512-323-5543'))

[('514', '552', '2345'), ('512', '323', '5543')]
```

Comment: Appreciate it!!

Answer (score -1):

"." in regex matches any character. If you want to match a literal . you need to use \. to escape it